# Visual Studio add a virtual path to the web app when debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017

I'm facing a something that I didn't set: Whenever I debug a web application, the web site opens as follows:

Expected: http://localhost/car-web/

Actual: http://localhost/car-web/(S(udtqwib0x5caixvbaccccj4o))/

There is a virtual path **/(S(udtqwib0x5caixvbaccccj4o))** added to the URL that I have not set anywhere. Where is this coming from and why?

web.config:

```
<configuration>

    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />

        <sectionGroup name="bundleTransformer">
            <section name="core" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Configuration.CoreSettings, BundleTransformer.Core" />
            <section name="uglify" type="BundleTransformer.UglifyJs.Configuration.UglifySettings, BundleTransformer.UglifyJs" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    </appSettings>

    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" />
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="4.7" targetFramework="4.7.2" maxRequestLength="51200" executionTimeout="300" encoderType="System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <globalization uiCulture="auto:en" culture="en-GB" />
        <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="true" timeout="60"></sessionState>
        <pages>
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
    </system.web>

    <system.web.extensions>
        <scripting>
            <webServices>
                <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644" />
            </webServices>
        </scripting>
    </system.web.extensions>

    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
            <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
            <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
            <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
            <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
            <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/otf" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
        </staticContent>
        <modules>
            <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
        </modules>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Node" value="Local" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
        <!--
        <tracing>
            <traceFailedRequests>
                <add path="*">
                    <traceAreas>
                        <add provider="ASP" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="ASPNET" areas="Infrastructure,Module,Page,AppServices" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="ISAPI Extension" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI,WebSocket" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    </traceAreas>
                    <failureDefinitions statusCodes="100.1-999.999" />
                </add>
            </traceFailedRequests>
        </tracing>
        -->
    </system.webServer>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <!-- ... -->
    </system.serviceModel>

    <runtime>
        <!-- ... -->
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Overlapped" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Security.SecureString" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.StackTrace" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Globalization.Extensions" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Sockets" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.Tracing" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.IO.Compression" publicKeyToken="B77A5C561934E089" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.Common" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Xml.XPath.XDocument" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core" publicKeyToken="c608b2a8cc9e4472" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="BundleTransformer.Core" publicKeyToken="973c344c93aac60d" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.9.213.0" newVersion="1.9.213.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Collections.Immutable" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.4.0" newVersion="1.2.4.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>

    <log4net>
        <!-- ... -->
    </log4net>

    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
            <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>

    <bundleTransformer xmlns="http://tempuri.org/BundleTransformer.Configuration.xsd">
        <core>
            <css>
                <translators>
                    <add name="NullTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Translators.NullTranslator, BundleTransformer.Core" enabled="false" />
                </translators>
                <postProcessors>
                    <add name="UrlRewritingCssPostProcessor" type="BundleTransformer.Core.PostProcessors.UrlRewritingCssPostProcessor, BundleTransformer.Core" useInDebugMode="false" />
                </postProcessors>
                <minifiers>
                    <add name="NullMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Minifiers.NullMinifier, BundleTransformer.Core" />
                </minifiers>
                <fileExtensions>
                    <add fileExtension=".css" assetTypeCode="Css" />
                </fileExtensions>
            </css>
            <js>
                <translators>
                    <add name="NullTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Translators.NullTranslator, BundleTransformer.Core" enabled="false" />
                </translators>
                <minifiers>
                    <add name="NullMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Minifiers.NullMinifier, BundleTransformer.Core" />
                    <add name="UglifyJsMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.UglifyJs.Minifiers.UglifyJsMinifier, BundleTransformer.UglifyJs" />
                </minifiers>
                <fileExtensions>
                    <add fileExtension=".js" assetTypeCode="JavaScript" />
                </fileExtensions>
            </js>
        </core>
    </bundleTransformer>

</configuration>
```

Project -> Properties -> Web Tab:
[image: Setup]

Comment: Show us your Properties/launchSettings.json file please. (Or whatever configuration you have for launching your project)

Comment: Updated question

Comment: I thought this would be a local machine issue but as it turns out, the virtual folder with different random characters is being rendered on production IIS as now. I really need to know what this is.